# Business Objects XI-Can a *non* Admin copy a report from one environment to another?

Tags: business-objects

Pardon me if the subject  question doesn't make sense and let me try to explain.

We have a production environment of BO pointing to a production database. And we have a  development environment pointing to a dev database.

When a user complains that a report doesn't work, we would like to copy the report to the dev environment and after making the fix, ensure that the report now works. The problem is that we were told by our BO admin that one must have Admin privileges to be able to do this and getting an Admin to do this requires an act of congress plus one week.

Given developers admin access to the production environment is no a posisblity, obviously. But I find it hard to believe that one should have to have admin rights to be able to do this. Does this seem right?

-Just a rookie BO user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm just confirming Sivvy's answer.

I have just attempted to use the Import Wizard to migrate a report without being an administrator and I was not allowed to even log in.  In addition to needing to be a member of Administrator group the log in needs to have an Enterprise log in account in Business Objects.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure you need admin rights to transfer anything in cross server in business objects. I don't believe that there is any single right that would allow that.